# RabbitMQ set queue Parameters while connecting through camel

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, javabeans, amqp, endpoint

I am trying to connect to RabbitMQ queues present in the server using `apache-camel` configuration.

It works fine when I create the queues with `durable` field `false` and `auto-delete` field `true`. But doesn't work when either of them is otherwise.

`applicationContext.xml` file looks like this -

```
<bean id="customConnectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    <property name="port" value="5672" />
    <property name="username" value="guest" />
    <property name="password" value="guest" />
    <property name="virtualHost" value="Test" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="testBean" class="test.TestBean" />

<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from
            uri="rabbitmq://localhost:5672/ex1?connectionFactory=#customConnectionFactory&amp;queue=Q1&amp;autoDelete=true&amp;durable=true" />
        <to uri="bean:testBean?method=hello" />  <!-- This method consumes and prints the message -->
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Here I need to specify the properties `autoDelete` and `durable` for the queue `Q1` **not** the exchange `ex1`. (I have already specified for the exchange in the URI)

As the error is -

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'auto_delete' for queue 'Q1' in vhost 'Test': received 'true' but current is 'false', class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

Here **reply-code=406** indicates that the parameters of queues/exchanges are not matching with the actual configuration. Its because of the queues properties here.

As I don't have the access to the remote queues, I cannot change the properties of queues. (Example I stated here is localhost)

Note: I have a requirement of doing this using spring beans only.

Comment: Have you deleted the queues? You cannot change the properties of a declared queue/exchange/etc. without deleting it first.

Comment: I cannot delete the queues. I dont have admin access. I wanted to know how I can pass the queue parameters in camel configuration.